# How can I apply effects to a character based on the tiles it occupies?

Tags: java, game-design

A mechanic of my game is that when a `Character` (Actor) steps on some specific tiles, they should be affected by status effects like slow, poison, burn, etc. These effects lasts only while the `Character` is on the effect tile. The character may be a lot larger than the tile. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check what tile your character is currently on.  If that tile is an active effect tile, then activate that effect on your character.

What have you tried up to now?  Can you provide code snippets that we can work off of to help you resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you have some structure that describes properties of a tile:

```
class Tile {
  int sprite;
  int movementCost;
  ...
}
```

To that data structure, add a list of effect references which point to the effects to apply to a character while that character is on the tile.

Since a character is potentially larger than a tile, it can potentially "occupy" more than one tile for the purpose of having effects applied. It should be fairly easy to get the range of tiles covered by a character of known width and height given the character's current origin tile position and the width and height of a tile (`ceiling(characterWidth / tileWidth)` tells you how many tiles the character covers along the X axis; Y can be computed similarly).

With that information you can collect the set of tiles covered by any given character, and then:

```
foreach (tile in tiles) {
  foreach (effect in tile.effectsToApply) {
    character.applyEffect(effect);
  }
}
```

Optionally, you can check if an effect is already applied to a character in the inner loop and skip it if you'd prefer tiles not to "stack" their effects.